# xcode backward compatibility methods

Tags: ios, sdk, backwards-compatibility

I've a project that runs perfectly (I hope :)) on ios 6 SDK.

When I try to test it on ios 5 simulator, I've a blank view so I suppose that I've used some uncompatible methods.

How Can I discover and verify which methods doesn't works?

Or are there some problems with my xib?

EDIT:
My appDelegate code:

```
LoginViewController *loginViewController =
[[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:"LoginViewController.xib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];
navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;

if (![self connect]){}

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: some things changed (like order of calls and orientation) but if something is supported in 6 but not in 5, it would crash with "unknown selector" ;)

Comment: check your log if there is any information about any crash?

Comment: I haven't any error log :( I suppose that my blank screen problem could be caused by erroneous xib, so I've tried also with another xib with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

"Apple and backward compatibility" is an oxymoron. It is not interesting to Apple if you publish apps that use older than the current iOS version, you know how hard they force developers and consumers to move on. I wouldn't bother and I would set the bottom line at 6.